# How do I get the 'Flexslider' current image number into a variable which I can use in a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I am using [flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/). There is an example under the advanced tap on [this](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) page (in the section **"The new, robust Callback API"** where they use `slider.currentSlide` to get the number of the current slide.

How can I access this value in a completely different function? I am thinking of a global variable but I don't know if that will work and I don't know if it's possible to declare a variable within a function as global.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can declare a global variable and set the value in the after callback function. Here's some pseudocode to help you get the idea:

```
var curSlide;
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    after: function(slider) {
      window.curSlide = slider.currentSlide;
    }
  });
});

function useCurSlideHere() {
  alert(window.curSlide);
}
```

Although ideally you'd avoid using a global variable and you could make the useCurSlideHere function into a class which you create an instance of on window.load and use it when you pass the curSlide variable in the after callback function.

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var customSlider = new useCurSlideHere();
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    after: function(slider) {
      customSlider.setCurSlide(slider.currentSlide);
    }
  });      
});

function useCurSlideHere() {
  this.curSlide = 0;

  this.setCurSlide = function(curSlide) {
    this.curSlide = curSlide;
  }

  this.getCurSlide= function() {
    alert(this.curSlide);
  }
}
```

EDIT: Edited the answer to use slider.currentSlide.

Comment: Good answer, but there's actually a much cleaner and simpler way of doing this, please see my answer below.

Comment: doesn't work anymore slider.currentSlide is undefined. @Lewis's answer does the job.

Answer (score 36):

You can avoid global variables by accessing the flexslider object with:

```
$(element).data('flexslider')
```

So in your case you'd use:

```
$(element).data('flexslider').currentSlide
```